# angularjs when i should use a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am working with javascript and angularjs for about a month.
But i'm still not sure, when i should use a directive or not.

**Example:**
I want to show appointments in a table with the date as tableheader.
On the left of the table i have a button, where i can load the appointments
of the previous week and on the right for the next week.

My **first approach** would be: 
I have a viewmodel/controller which holds the data for the actual week.
Then i add two methods on the controller: loadPreviousWeek, loadNextWeek which get's
the data from a appointmentProvider.
In my view i add a ng-click directive to the buttons  which call the functions of the controller.

After i read a bit about directives this would be my **second approach**:
I have a AppointmentService which holds the actual week. This service
can load the next week and the previous week. Then i create a directive, loadWeek,
which adds the onClick event to the element who uses's it. This onClick
method call's the methods from the appointmentService. And my view directly
binds to the appointmentService througt the controller.

Which approach would be better? Correct me please, if i am completely wrong.
And can you give me some other examples from the practice for directives?

Sincerely,
Cristan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a use case for a custom directive to me. Directives are used to link your controllers/scopes to the DOM (remember, all the ng-xy bindings are directives provided by AngularJS). A directive mostly is somehow linked to a scope (and it's controller therefore).

Defining the information which you want to show and changing them based on the user inputs is a typical task for the controller. Do you have any problems implementing the controller or are you considering directives?

Comment: Till now i only used my first approach for things like that, but then i read this article: [link](http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/) and i think he describes the using of directives a bit like my second approach. This is the reason for my question.

Comment: I don't agree at all with the writer of this article. Executing business functionality directly from a directive makes it very difficult to test and it bypasses every possibility for the controller to handle the event in a different way. So every time you need a similar logic, you end up writing a new directive, THAT is what you need to avoid (talking about DRY). Putting this service-call in the controller doesn't violate the DRY principle at all (because you put the real logic in your service). You could even reuse the controller in multiple views.

Comment: I forgot to mention that MVC and MVVM patterns (or Model View Whatever as AngularJS likes to describe its pattern) usually are designed to handle all user interactions with the application in the controller. So as a general guideline, use the controller. This may not be applicable in every scenario, but I think your use case is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a directive *could* be what what you're looking for, but you may also just want a controller in this situation. The controller handles getting the loadPrevious/next events and uses the service to get the data.

Where you would want to involve the directive, in my understanding, is if you wanted to create an html template that went along with it which can do cool stuff like transclude other elements.

For convenience: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive